# Responsive command line output in python

Tags: python, terminal

I have a JSON file which contents I would like to see in the console, these contents change frequently. I would like to achieve functionality similar to top or htop on Linux, i.e. a tabular view taking the entire console, refreshing but not deleting previous commands from the terminal (so no `os.system("clear")` if possible. I don't need to interact with the data, I'm just interested in the output.

The amount of data is not set, but each data point has a name and a value that need to be displayed. I'm looking for something like this:

```
| variable1 | variable2 | variable3 | variable4 |
|   3.33    |    2.22   |   44.55   |    3.22   |
| variable5 | variable6 | variable7 |
|   3.33    |    2.21   |   4.55    |
```

I was looking for a library that could help, but I couldn't find one.
Only solution I thought of consists of printing and clearing the screen over and over again.

```
while True:
        try:
            with open(fn) as f:
                data =json.load(f)
                vs_df = pd.DataFrame({"name": data[0], "value": data[1], "timestamp": data[2]})
            
            os.system("clear")
            max_row_length = 4
            current_row_length = 0
            current_row = ""
            for index, row in vs_df.iterrows():
                if current_row_length >= max_row_length - 1:
                    print(current_row)
                    current_row_length = 0
                    current_row = ""
                else:
                    current_row += f'     {row["name"]}: {row["value"]}'
                    current_row_length += 1
            time.sleep(0.5)
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            pass
```

This solution causes flickering.

Comment: Have you checked out `blessed`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thank you. blessed is exactly what I was looking for. New code looks something like this:

```
from blessed import Terminal

term = Terminal()
with term.cbreak(), term.hidden_cursor():
    # send the cursor to the beginning and clear screen
    print(term.home + term.clear)
    # repeat until q is pressed
    while term.inkey(timeout=0.02) != 'q':
        # move cursor to the top left
        txt = term.move_xy(0, 0) + '\n '
        try:
            with open(fn) as f:
                data =json.load(f)
                vs_df = pd.DataFrame({"name": data[0], "value": data[1], "timestamp": data[2]})
            
            max_row_length = 4
            current_row_length = 0
            current_row = ""
            for index, row in vs_df.iterrows():
                if current_row_length >= max_row_length:
                    # add row to the output
                    txt += term.center(current_row)
                    current_row_length = 0
                    current_row = ""
                else:
                    current_row += f'|{name:>32}:  {row["value"]:<8}'
                    current_row_length += 1
            time.sleep(0.5)
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            pass
        # print output in the console
        print(txt)
    print(term.home + term.clear)
```

blessed has many formatting options I will definitely look into.